# How to interpret the interest rate of treasury notes?

Tags: united-states, investing, terminology, treasury

I am new to investing in the US and money terms in English, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

From [this table](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/annceresult/annceresult.htm), I can see, for example, that the most recent 2-year treasury note sale had an interest rate of 0.625%.

Is this a monthly, quarterly, semesterly, or yearly interest rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That 0.625% is the annual interest rate you'll receive.  It is paid out in two, semi-annual payments. That is, every six months you'll receive a check for roughly 0.3125%.

https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/products/prod_tnotes_glance.htm

Comment: If inflation rose to 1%, would that mean I would lose money?

Comment: Pretty much. You don't lose that money, it's just that the things you can buy with the money are 1% more expensive.